# I Want to use Google Maps in my Java Project

Tags: java, google-maps

I am currently working on project which tries to help locate various land marks on a map. Currently I have saved 5 to 6 google maps images and using them in my project. What I want is user chooses a map of his location/interest and save that part of map as .jpec and rest my project work on that image.

```
      int x = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(x == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
             f = fc.getSelectedFile();
             str = f.getAbsolutePath();
            setTitle("Now Showing : "+str);
         lp2_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon((new ImageIcon(str)).getImage().getScaledInstance( 600, 600,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));



       }
```

I am using this method to open an image.

Comment: Is there a question in there? Or are you asking to have code provided to you?

Comment: its a question sir ... sorry for not putting ? mark.

Comment: What I want that i should not open an pre-saved image, but it should be loaded from Google maps, and I have no Idea how to proceed ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking to display a satellite map image for a specific latitude longitude (without the google maps panning/zooming etc), then you should check out [Google Static Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

You just need to build a URL string, then make an HTTP request (from your java implementation) for the image (in whatever format you like).  You can specify a whole bunch of [parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#URL_Parameters) in the URL to get the satellite image you are after:

[image]

From the URL:

```
http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=40,26&zoom=1&size=150x112&maptype=satellite&key=ABQIAAAAgb5KEVTm54vkPcAkU9xOvBR30EG5jFWfUzfYJTWEkWk2p04CHxTGDNV791-cU95kOnweeZ0SsURYSA&format=jpg
```

An example how to save a Image from an URL:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class SaveImageFromUrl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String imageUrl = "http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=40,26&zoom=1&size=150x112&maptype=satellite&key=ABQIAAAAgb5KEVTm54vkPcAkU9xOvBR30EG5jFWfUzfYJTWEkWk2p04CHxTGDNV791-cU95kOnweeZ0SsURYSA&format=jpg";
        String destinationFile = "image.jpg";

        saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);
    }

    public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I hope that was what you were searching for, i think its an easy way to use google maps, so u dont need to use a big api. If this helps you can mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: But how to store this image in my disk so that I can use it for future use ?

Comment: i hope my edit will help u

Comment: trying to implement it in my project sir ... Thankx a Lot ...

Comment: tell us if u got it to work ;)